# Change column format from 'factor' to 'date'

Tags: ggplot2

I would like to change the format of a column called "SampleStart" in my dataframe "xray50g".
Checking the data in this column shows it is currently in the "factor" format -

```
> lapply(xray50g,class)
$SampleStart
[1] "factor"
```

I would like to change the data format to "Date" in the form "%d/%m/%Y"

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks.

[image: column]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this shortens year to last two digits, but it's a start, and the class is at least correct.

```
library(chron)

x <- as.factor(c("2016-10-26", "2016-10-26", "2016-10-26", "2016-10-26"))
z <-format(as.Date(x), "%d/%m/%Y")
date <-chron(z, format = c(dates =  "d/m/Y"))
```